# Check USB mouse for malicious code

Tags: malware, usb, trojan

When I first used this mouse and keyboard, my PC died shortly after. Today I used it and it somehow corrupted my Linux.

I once put a clean Linux on a laptop and plugged this mouse in and left it, several times the laptop came out of sleep without being touched.

I have suspicions that it's effectively a "rubberducky" and delivering a payload.

Is there a way to determine the risk? Can I install hard or soft USB monitoring?

[Here's a link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/UrChoiceLtd-T6-Ergonomic-Keyboard-Standard/dp/B01M1VB1ZZ/ref=pd_day0_2?pd_rd_w=axnut&pf_rd_p=8ec13b8a-30d2-48fc-8503-84c56766370d&pf_rd_r=3TAEBNKBENSGBF6K8GPQ&pd_rd_r=5fa22003-87aa-4ba0-bbb9-63edb90fc5eb&pd_rd_wg=BeZ1l&pd_rd_i=B01M1VB1ZZ&psc=1) to the mouse.

Comment: I removed all the irrelevant details in the post to focus on the question you actually asked.

Comment: or a bit of dust went past the sensor and the mouse thought you moved it by 1 pixel...

Comment: I find it more likely that this is an electrical problem, like a short-circuit.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible for a USB mouse to do something bad. But unlike a keyboard, a mouse can't easily control things on your computer since it can't see the screen to know where to click. To do something bad, it would have to turn in to a device such as a keyboard or other device with a driver that could be exploited.

Next time you'll have to capture your kernel message log and see if new USB devices were plugged in. For example, if your mouse changes in to a flash drive, you'll see the new device being recognized by the kernel in the logs.